# Only on Safari, why would an SVG feColorMatrix filter cause clipping?

Tags: html, svg, safari

I'm using SVG graphics to display a two signal level meters. The bars of the meters are green, but since the signal from only one source is being displayed at a given time, I use a filter to tint the meter for the unused signal blue. Here's how the meters look on Chrome or Firefox:

[image: screenshot Chrome]

Here's what happens on Safari (notice the blue-tinted meter on the right is clipped on both the left and right edges):

[image: screenshot Safari]

If I use Safari's web console to inspect the element, then uncheck the filter, the clipping goes away without changing anything else (expect the meter becomes green again too, of course). I can be pretty sure that it's the filter causing the clipping, and not some other problem like bad positioning or overlap from an opaque component.

[image: web console]

This is how the filter is defined

```html
        <filter id="meter-tint">
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
        </filter>
```

And this is the SVG to which the filter is being applied:

```
        <svg id="outdoor-meter-2" class="svg-flow" svg-flow="current-temp,dx=-3.8,dy=-3.5" width="2" height="1.6">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 640 512" class="signal-meter">
            <rect x= "24" y="384" width="80" height="128" class="signal-bar-1"/>
            <rect x="152" y="288" width="80" height="224" class="signal-bar-2"/>
            <rect x="280" y="192" width="80" height="320" class="signal-bar-3"/>
            <rect x="408" y= "96" width="80" height="416" class="signal-bar-4"/>
            <rect x="536" y=  "0" width="80" height="512" class="signal-bar-5"/>
            <line style="display: none; stroke-width: 40px; stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0);" class="no-signal" x1="64" y1="40" x2="576" y2="424"/>
          </svg>
        </svg>
```

**Update**:

Just to emphasize how weird and inconsistent this is, I found that adding an invisible rectangle like this:

`<rect x="0" y="0" width="640" height="512" style="fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"></rect>`

...fixes all of the clipping except the leftmost bar, and this:

`<rect x="0" y="0" width="640" height="640" style="fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"></rect>`

...fixes all clipping, left and right, but shifts the graphic upward several pixels. `height="639"` isn't enough to fix any clipping on the left, then bumping up to 640 fixes it all.

This makes no sense!

Comment: Move the filter out of CSS and put it directly in the SVG and see if there is still a problem. Safari sometimes has sizing and other problems applying SVG filters via CSS.

Comment: The filter is in defined in SVG, as shown above. The only CSS is `.meter-tint { filter: url(#meter-tint); }`, so that the filter becomes a CSS class. If I don't use that CSS class definition, how would I programmatically apply and remove the filter via JavaScript? Add and remove a filter attribute?

Comment: I tried getting rid of even that little bit of CSS, adding and removing a filter attribute instead. Same result, unfortunately. And while there's no class I can toggle off in the web console, I can delete the attribute in the console, and that makes the clipping go away too.